# Android Manifest code for Parse Push Receiver

Tags: android, push-notification, android-manifest, android-notifications

I have followed the guidelines mentioned in `parse.com` and tried all helps from stackoverflow. But I am unable to receive any Parse Push Notification. The Dashboard shows Pushes Sent 0. Can anyone help me out on this. The code for

```
manifest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phpand"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.phpand.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.phpand.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity android:name=".ParseMainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.phpand" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyCustomReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

where `MainAppp` initializes the Parse, `ParseMainActivity`'s button click sends the push message and `MyCustomReceiver` is the BroadCastReceiver Class.

MyCustomReceiver class has:

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";
   public static final String intentAction = "SEND_PUSH";

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (intent == null) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
       } else {
          processPush(context, intent);
       }
   }

   private void processPush(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String action = intent.getAction();
       Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );
       if (action.equals(intentAction))
       {
           String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
           try {        
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
               Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
               Iterator<String> itr = json.keys();
               while (itr.hasNext()) {
                   String key = (String) itr.next();
               if (key.equals("customdata")) {    
                launchSomeActivity(context, json.getString(key));
                triggerBroadcastToActivity(context);
                createNotification(context);
                }
                    Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
               }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON failed!");
            }
       }
   }

   public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 45;
   private void createNotification(Context context) {
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(
               R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Successfully logged in");
       NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       mNotificationManager.notify(45, mBuilder.build());
   }

   private void launchSomeActivity(Context context, String datavalue) {
       Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopUp.class);
       pupInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
       pupInt.putExtra("customdata", datavalue);
       context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);   
   }

   private void triggerBroadcastToActivity(Context context) {
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(intentAction));
   }
}
```

Probably I must be missing something in the Manifest file, any help would save my week's due.

Comment: have you ever tried sending push using the dashboard you mentioned ?

Comment: yes I tried it from there too, is says Pushes Sent "0" to Target "Everyone"

Comment: if you have registered your app correctly you must see it in active installation. the size shows the number of registered devices in send push section. is that >0 ?

Comment: In the Core tab of parse, it displays the list of installed devices, with different ObjectId, appIdentifier with my package name.

Comment: and the pushes sent is always 0.

Comment: which means you have some problem registering your device into parse

Comment: not exactly I guess, because there are currently 12 installed devices showing up. Also whenever I uninstall and reinstall the app, the count increases by 1.